# Audit of what records a given user can see in SalesForce.com

Tags: salesforce, soql, salesforce-service-cloud

I am trying to determine a way to audit which records a given user can see by;

> Object Type
>
> Record Type
>
> Count of records

Ideally would also be able to see which fields for each object/record type the user can see.

We will need to repeat this often and for different users and in different orgs, so would like to avoid manually determining this.

My first thought was to create an app using the partner WSDL, but would like to ask if there are any easier approaches or perhaps existing solutions.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can follow the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_userrecordaccess.htm) to solve it, using a query similar to this one:

```
SELECT RecordId
     FROM UserRecordAccess
     WHERE UserId = [single ID]
     AND RecordId = [single ID]      //or Record IN [list of IDs]
     AND HasReadAccess = true
```

> The following query returns the records for which a queried user has
>   read access to.

In addition, you should add limit 1 and get from record metadata the object type,record type, and so on.

Comment: Martin, I think this might be part of the solution, but this query requires either a single id or set of ids.  Passing every record id that exists in any sizable org is not going to scale well.  Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the below (C# using the Partner WSDL) to get an idea of what kinds of objects the user had visibility into.

Just a quick'n'dirty utility for my own use (read - not prod code);

```
var service = new SforceService();

var result = service.login("UserName", "Password");

service.Url = result.serverUrl;
service.SessionHeaderValue = new SessionHeader { sessionId = result.sessionId };

var queryResult = service.describeGlobal();

int total = queryResult.sobjects.Count();

int batcheSize = 100;
var batches = Math.Ceiling(total / (double)batcheSize);


using (var output = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test\sfdcAccess.txt", false))
{

    for (int batch = 0; batch < batches; batch++)
    {
        var toQuery =
            queryResult.sobjects.Skip(batch * batcheSize).Take(batcheSize).Select(x => x.name).ToArray();

        var batchResult = service.describeSObjects(toQuery);

        foreach (var x in batchResult)
        {
            if (!x.queryable)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is not queryable", x.name);
                continue;
            }

            var test = service.query(string.Format("SELECT Id FROM {0} limit 100", x.name));

            if(test == null || test.records == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}:null records", x.name);
                continue;
            }

            foreach (var record in test.records)
            {
                output.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}",x.name, record.Id);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("{0}:\t{1} records(0)", x.name, test.size);
        }
    }
    output.Flush();
}
```